# Facebook images timeline block

Tags: javascript, media

Is there a module and/or jQuery solution how to show multiple images in a block like the Facebook gallery on people's timeline? The images are always well aligned regardless of their size and landscape/portrait position.

I'd like to use a similar approach for my blog articles - Upload like 3 or 4 images and some text. I included a screenshot of a Facebook post to give you an example of what I mean.

[image: Facebook timeline image block]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on a lot different ways regardless where you are using this, but it is mostly Front End question.

There is a [Grid Field Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/grid_field_formatter) module that can help you with this, but it is not the best solution.

> Grid Field Formatter module provides a simple way to overridde the
>   display of multi-value fields to show as a grid/table with a certain
>   number of columns.

Comment: I think this module uses only fix number of columns.

Comment: @mixerowsky Ok, thank you! I will check it out and accept your answer if the Grid Field Formatter module is of any use to me. Maybe the [Auto Image Style](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_image_style) module is more useful for what I want.